# Kivy - how to pass a variable to KV language using Clock

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to write a simple Countdown timer App using Kivy Framework. I've already counted all variables, all I need to do is to pass them to the KV language to display them. However, I'm stuck with passing the values.

```
import datetime
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, NumericProperty

class Counter_Timer(BoxLayout):
    days = StringProperty()
    hours = StringProperty()
    minutes = StringProperty()
    seconds = StringProperty()

    def update(self, dt):
        delta = datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 13, 3, 5) - datetime.datetime.now()
        self.days = str(delta.days)
        hour_string = str(delta).split(', ')[1]
        self.hours = hour_string.split(':')[0]
        self.minutes = hour_string.split(':')[1]
        self.seconds = hour_string.split(':')[2].split('.')[0]

class Counter(App):
    def build(self):
        counter = Counter_Timer()
        Clock.schedule_interval(counter.update, 1.0)
        return Counter_Timer()


if __name__=='__main__':
    Counter().run()
```

KV:

```
<Counter_Timer>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Label: 
        text: 'Days '
        font_size: '30dp'
    Label:
        font_size: '30dp'
        # text value with days left.
        text: root.days
```

The code results in no errors, but days left don't display.

I guess that the way I try to access the variable with root.property is ok, but does the usage of Clock change something ? Where is my mistake ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def build(self):
    counter = Counter_Timer()
    Clock.schedule_interval(counter.update, 1.0)
    return Counter_Timer()
```

You schedule an update to your counter instance, which works fine, but then you return a new, *different* `Counter_Timer`. You never change its properties, so its text never updates.

You simply need to `return counter` instead.